# Why two input boxes side by side inside div impose an extra padding-top?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a form with 2 columns using bootstrap. The fields name and street appear side by side (large screen) and no problem but on second rowzip code is not vertical aligned with City because zip code has 2 edit boxs. If i use just one edit box in zip code everything looks fine but if i use two edit boxes an extra pading top appears. Why?

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<H1>Hello</H1>
<P>Sample text here.</P> 

<section id="Delivery" class="Delivery-section">
 <div class="container">
  
  <div class="row" style='padding:0px'>
   <div class="col-sm-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-10" style='font-size: 20px;padding:0px;text-align:left;padding-left:10px'>
    <legend style='text-align:center'>Delivery Address</legend>
   </div>        
   <div class="col-sm-1">
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row" style='padding:0px'>    
   <div class="col-sm-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-5" style='font-size: 20px;padding:0px;text-align:left;padding-left:10px'>
    <span style='font-weight: bold;font-size:13px;'>Name: (*)</span><br>
    <input style="width:100%;font-size:12px;font-weight:regular;line-height:20px;" type="text" name="name" id="name" value='' size="30" />
   </div>      
   <div class="col-sm-5" style='font-size: 20px;padding:0px;text-align:left;padding-left:10px'>
    <span style='font-weight: bold;font-size:13px;'>Street: (*)</span><br>
    <input style="width:100%;font-size:12px;font-weight:regular;line-height:20px;" type="text" name="street" id="street" value='' size="30" />
   </div>  
   <div class="col-sm-1">
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row" style='padding:0px'>    
   <div class="col-sm-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-5" style='font-size: 20px;padding:0px;text-align:left;padding-left:10px;'>
    <span style='font-weight: bold;font-size:13px;'>City: (*)</span><br>
    <input style="width:100%;font-size:12px;font-weight:regular;line-height:20px;" type="text" name="city" id="city" value='' size="30" />
   </div>      
   <div class="col-sm-5" style='font-size: 20px;padding:0px;text-align:left;padding-left:10px;'>
    <span style='font-weight: bold;font-size:13px;'>Zip code: (*)</span><br>
    <input style="width:14%;font-size:12px;font-weight:regular;line-height:20px;" type="text" name="cp1" id="cp1" value='' size="30" />
    <input style="width:14%;font-size:12px;font-weight:regular;line-height:20px;" type="text" name="cp2" id="cp2" value='' size="30" />
   </div>  
   <div class="col-sm-1">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> 
</section>
```

Comment: [I cannot reproduce this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/wwc5akwj/)

Comment: try to remove every space between tags <input ....><input ....>, better to wrap that input inside another .col-sm-6 or so ....

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome but this effect is could be seen in all browsers. Ca not put a img here...

Comment: In the jsfiddle is seems ok but not on the browsers. Very strange

Comment: Here is an image of that: http://postimg.org/image/6u99oaecr

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem I just took out the `font-size:20px` out of problematic div element.  As to why this seems to have fixed the issue I cannot say because you have that in the other div elements as well and it doesn't seem to be a problem. I will say however that the font-size attribute does not need to be specified in the div elements as you are giving font-size to each of the elements individually, unless of course you were going to add or do have other elements that it are being used that are not in the code above. I also checked taking out the font-size attribute out of the other div elements and it has no negative effect.

Comment: I removed the font-size:20px and the problem remains... Please, try to put a border:1px solid red; for example in the zip code and city divs and you will see that zip code's div gets more height than the city div. Then remove the second edit box of zip code and you will see everything fine. It seems that it is the addition of the second zip code edit box that causes the problem... I am using Chrome v 43.0.2357.130 m

Comment: Just curious, which div did you take out the font-size from? I had no problem seeing the problem you were having, however now I see no problem after I took that out.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the code to show what you asked about re padding top etc. I removed one of the zip inputs... still no difference. (using chrome here).

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/m87xjczv/)**.

I removed all of the inline styles so the code is easier to read/follow.
I removed all of those blank divs you look to be using to offset/fill. That sort of blank divs like that all bar the most top can end up floating.
I replace this with `col-sm-offset-1` as you will see in the `row`.

I reworked the zip and city cols here.
Is this what you were looking for when you asked about vertically align the **zip** and the **city**?
I wasn't to sure.

Image is of large screen view.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}    
.space {
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}  

.address {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align:center;
}    
.inputs {
    width:100%;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:300;
    line-height:20px;
}
.zip {
    width:14%; 
    font-size:12px; 
    font-weight:300; 
    line-height:20px; 
}
.labels {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding:0px; 
    padding-left:0px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class="container col-lg-12 space"></div>
<div class="container col-lg-12">

      <H1>Hello</H1>
<P>Sample text here.</P> 

<section id="Delivery" class="Delivery-section">
 <div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
  <!--<div class="col-sm-1">
   </div>-->
   <div class="col-sm-10 address" >
    <legend>Delivery Address</legend>
   </div>        
  <!--<div class="col-sm-1">
   </div> -->
  </div>
  
  <div class="row col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">    
  <!-- <div class="col-sm-1">
   </div>-->
   <div class="col-sm-5">
    <span class='labels'>Name: (*)</span><br>
    <input class='inputs' type="text" name="name" id="name" value='' />
   </div>      
   <div class="col-sm-5">
    <span class='labels'>Street: (*)</span><br>
    <input class='inputs' type="text" name="street" id="street" value='' />
   </div>  
  <!-- <div class="col-sm-1">
   </div>-->
  <!--</div>-->
  
  <div class="row col-sm-5">    
  <!-- <div class="col-sm-1">
   </div>-->
   <div class="col-sm-12">
    <span class='labels'>City: (*)</span><br>
    <input class='inputs' type="text" name="city" id="city" value='' />
   </div>      
   <div class="col-sm-12">
    <span class='labels'>Zip code: (*)</span><br>
    <input class="zip" type="text" name="cp1" id="cp1" value='' />
    <input class="zip" type="text" name="cp2" id="cp2" value='' />
   </div>  
  <!-- <div class="col-sm-1">
   </div>-->
  </div>
 </div>
    </div>
</section> 
        
</div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**Added to this post**

Using your original code as is this is what I see in a large view, both inputs are aligned.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes, if i run code snippet it looks fine, but try to enlarge screen in order to put zip code below street and you will see the problem. I am using chrome but i can see the problem in all browsers

Comment: Hi, Please show some screen shots of what you see. Enlarge the screen?? What do you mean? When viewed on large screen I see no change. Also show a screen shot/mockup of how you want it.

Comment: I dont know how to put an image here :-( (Enlarge = see the page in a wide screen in order to see the zip code below street field). In yor answer the zip code is below the city. That is not what i want

Comment: in the jsfiddle it works great but not on browsers. Please, copy past it into an html file and open file in chrome. Please see: http://postimg.org/image/6u99oaecr

Comment: Do you mean copy my code or your original code?  Yes I can now see in your image you have some padding only between bottom of the zip text and the top of the zip input.

Comment: I added to my post a screenshot of your code, large view not in the fiddle. It is all even.

Comment: My god, it is good... In which browser? Country settings influencies?  I dont know...  What i can see i that in your case and in  Fiddle case the vertical space among elements is greater than in all my browsers... I have tried to add some (vertical) padding among elements but the problem remains...